windows 10 - strange explorer folder behavior based on folder name
I don't even know what to call this, but
If I create a folder in a specific path ~/sync/dev
The title bar changes and becomes white when entering this folder:
entering dev
outside of dev
I don't know what is triggering this behavior and I can't turn it off.
Renaming the path to say ~/syncx/dev doesn't trigger this behavior.
On a different machine, this doesn't occur.
It's a normal empty folder.
It does not appear when having a similar folder path somewhere else on the drive.

The issue was resolved, in a very strange way. I don't know what happened, but it's fixed.

rename the sync folder to syncc
restart computer
create a new folder path called sync/dev/
enter dev ( issue persists )
delete sync folder
rename syncc to sync
icon of folder sync got replaced by default folder symbol
change the icon of folder sync again (affects desktop.ini)
issue fixed

So could it be that there was something odd inside desktop.ini?

Strange indeed. This is what immediately comes to mind:
Custom Themes/Third-Party Software: Some customisation software can change the appearance of Windows elements like the title bar. This might be triggered specifically by folder names or locations.
File Explorer Extensions: Third-party extensions that hook into File Explorer could change the title bar appearance based on certain conditions.
Corrupted Display Settings: While less likely, a corrupted display setting associated with that specific folder path might be the issue.
Sync Software Interference: Your sync software (~/sync/...) may be doing something in the background when it detects the "dev" folder.
What I suggest you do:
Check for Customisation Software:
Do you have any programs that alter Windows themes, icons, or UI elements? Try temporarily disabling them to see if that makes a difference.
Look in the settings of that software for any option that might specifically affect folders.
Investigate File Explorer Extensions:
You can use tools like "ShellExView" (It's a free utility ) to list and disable File Explorer extensions. Disable them one by one to see if any are causing the behaviour.
Reset Display Settings (Less Likely):
Right-click on your desktop and go to "Display settings".
Look for a reset option within the settings, but be aware this might reset other display customisations.
Examine Sync Software Behavior:
Does your sync software have any special features related to development folders or folders named "dev"? Sometimes sync software can add overlays or modify the view of folders it's configured to monitor.
Thoroughly review the settings in your sync software.
Clean Boot:
Perform a clean boot of Windows to disable non-essential startup programs and services temporarily. :
Operating System: What version of Windows are you using?
Sync Software: Which sync software are you using (e.g., OneDrive, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.)
If possible, can you provide a screenshot showing the title bar both inside and outside the "dev" folder?

the sync software I'm using is syncthing, but it is not running and its very non-invasive on folders. I use Start11 as a start menu customizer but I disabled it and the weird thing still occurs. Also my second machine is somewhat a mirror when it comes to this and it also has Start11 and syncthing installed. So this can't be it.

could check in autoruns if there is something?

I disabled anything non microsoft in ShellExView. Restarted explorer, and it's still the same.
